# Create a JSON object using an array of nodes

Tags: node.js, json

I the results of a table that gives me the dynamic hierarchy of fields that i am needing to use to create a JSON object from.

EX:

```
[ [ 'request', 'cycleRange' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'from' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to', 'month' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to', 'year' ],
  [ 'request', 'datestmt' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran', 'datePost' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran', 'dateTo' ] ]
```

The JSON object i am expecting to create with this sample should be:

```
let expected = {
    request: {
        cycleRange: {
            from: null,
            to: {
                month: null,
                year: null
            }
        },
        datestmt: null,
        singleTran: {
            datePost: null,
            dateTo: null
        }
    }
};
```

I am using this function to try and build the object, but i am only getting the final array as the object:

```
let final = {};
for (let i of heirarchy) {
    assign(final, i, null);
}    

function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
    let lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
    let key;
    let i;

    for (i=0; i<lastKeyIndex; i++) {
        key = keyPath[i];

        if (!(key in obj)) {
            obj[key] = {};
        } else {
            if (i !== lastKeyIndex) {
                obj[key] = {};
            }
        }

        obj = obj[key];
    }

    obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
}
```

Currently my results i am only getting: (the last index of my source hierarchy)

```
{"request":{"singleTran":{"dateTo":null}}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

because `obj` is referencing `final`, this line is likely causing you mischief:

```
        obj = obj[key];
```

This will overwrite the `obj` (in this case `final`) every iteration of hte loop. I would recommend keeping track of a separate variable so that `final` remains un-mutated

Comment: I figured that was the case, but i need to pass in the previous result of the loop into the new loop to be mutated correctly.  Or find some way of merging all of the results into the final object.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution but I think there is a lot of room for simplification and improvement, also I replaced null by {}.

You could use _.set from lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set to replace set in my example.

```js
const array = [ [ 'request', 'cycleRange' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'from' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to', 'month' ],
  [ 'request', 'cycleRange', 'to', 'year' ],
  [ 'request', 'datestmt' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran', 'datePost' ],
  [ 'request', 'singleTran', 'dateTo' ] ];
  


const set = (path, obj) => path.split('.').reduce((o,i)=> {
     return o[i] ? o[i] : o[i] = {};
}, obj)

let myNewObject = {};
let path = '';

array.forEach(element => {
  path = '';
  element.forEach(key => {
     path = path ? path + '.' + key : key;
     set(path, myNewObject);
  });
});

console.log(myNewObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using package deepmerge to merge the individual results into my final object

```
const deepmerge = require('deepmerge');
let final = {};
for (let i of heirarchy) {
    let temp = {};
    assign(temp, i, null);
    final = deepmerge(final, temp);
}
```